# Embed Instagram Feed Plain HTML

Tags: html, instagram, embed, feed

I created my photography website with a program called blocsapp. Now I want to embed my instagram feed. I only found the information how to embed a single post or how to use a third party to embed the feed, but I don't want to navigate to a third partys website when clicking on my feed. 
In blocsapp I can enter a HTML code, but only plain HTML.

Could you please help me?

Comment: I want to know, how I can embed my feed. Instagram provides the embedding code for a single post, but not for the whole feed.

Comment: @SANM2009 if you had experience embedding instagram feeds instead of posts then it would be quite clear what the question is.  Your claim - No one can help you - may still be true and a damning judgement on Instagram.  All solutions I found use the old depreciated API